# Syntax error on int list with .split()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, terminal

Not sure why I seem to be getting this syntax error, when I run the code in pycharm it works just fine

I have:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

from DiceRolls import RandomDiceRoll

num = [int(n) for n in input("Enter Numbers: ").split(",")]
for n in num:
    print(RandomDiceRoll.diceRoll(n))
```

And the RandomDiceRoll does this:

```
import sys
import random

def diceRoll(n1):
    w = random.randint(1,n1)
    return w
```

Now when I run this in pycharm, it works great, and prints the results I want.

However if I run it from terminal with python scriptName.py, I get this:

```
Enter Numbers: 4 0 0 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "userEnter.py", line 9, in <module>
    num = [int(n) for n in input("Enter Numbers: ").split(",")]
  File "<string>", line 1
    4 0 0 
      ^
```

I feel like I am doing something that I should pickup on, but I can't seem to find it, any help would be awesome!

Comment: I guess the terminal is usin py2 ... Try running using Py3 (In Linux --- `python3 scriptName.py` Dont know in OsX)

Comment: yep that was it, after that it was a string literal because of the ',' in the split that I didn't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your command-line is using python2 and not python3.

You have two options now

- Execute the script using python 3 as in `python3 scriptName.py`
- Convert the code into py2 (Bad alternative) as in `num = [int(n) for n in raw_input("Enter Numbers: ").split(",")]`

As you have not used `,` to delimit, you can as well remove that and use  .

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 2.7

Code look fine, I think you enter wrong input i.e. without `,`

code:

```
num = [int(n) for n in raw_input("Enter Numbers: ").split(",")]

print "num:-", num
```

output:

Invalid value enter by user:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
Enter Numbers: 4 0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5.py", line 91, in <module>
    num = [int(n) for n in raw_input("Enter Numbers: ").split(",")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 0 0'
```

Valid value enter by user:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
Enter Numbers: 4, 0, 0
num:- [4, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminal was pointing to Python 2, changed to python 3 and it works.